# iOS: Getting Notified When a Tweet Matching a Specific Phrase is Immediately Sent Out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, twitter

There's a specific user that tweets out a tweet (with a secret link and phrase) every month. What I want is to monitor that account, and the moment it posts the tweet, I want to be able to get notified within my app, and then do something.

Here's what I know:

User Account
The Phrase within that tweet
The time it is tweeted every month (i.e. 6am on the 4th saturday).

What I don't know:
The actual link to be tweeted.

My goal is to immediately know when it is sent out, so that I can open the link asap (time is super crucial).

Now a days there are many third party libraries, and tools that allow you to pull and display tweets. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Should I use twitter's streaming api, or their rest api? Any help would be appreciated!

I would prefer it if no authentication would be required. Thanks so much and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [User streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/user) to immediately receive a tweet as soon as it's published. I would create a specific Twitter account for this and only follow the Twitter account you wish to monitor. Use the `with=followings` parameter to receive the tweets from the account you want to monitor. Since you know these tweets are only occurring monthly at a specific time, you could limit connecting to the streaming API to a narrow window around the time the tweet is expected.

Comment: Hi neilco! I've been reading about user streaming API, but if I'm planning to incpororate this into an iOS app with potentially over 20,000 users, would this still work? Or would it be limited.

Comment: @user1886754 No, it would not. You'd be better off implementing a server-side stream client (i.e. a single connection to the Twitter API) and then handling notifying 20K+ users from there.